# AlertDialog button area background color Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to change background color for button area in alert dialog.
I have done with title background but can't find solution to change color or add divider to button area.

This is how looks now.

[image]

And code

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.MyDialogTheme)
            .setCustomTitle(custom_dialog_header)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                    selectedItem = selectedIndex;
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int linkID) {
                    String[] files = links.split(",");
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show();
```

And here is style

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>

    <item name="android:background">#282828</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorSwipe</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSwipe</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `create()` on builder object instead of `show()` to create an `AlertDialog` object.
Then, you can change any part of your dialog such as button area using `setOnShowListener`. this listener is called after your dialog is created, so we use it to avoid nullpointer exception.

```
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.MyDialogTheme)
        .setCustomTitle(custom_dialog_header)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selectedIndex) {
                int selectedItem = selectedIndex;
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int linkID) {
                String[] files = links.split(",");
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
        // to change background of positive button
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
        // to change background of button area
        ButtonBarLayout b = (ButtonBarLayout)(dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getParent());
        b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
    }
});
dialog.show();
```